# What are the tricks that make stackexchange's pagespeed that fast?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, performance

I seriously think that one of the main secrets of this site's success is that it loads pages very fast. Unlike other websites, I don't have to wait much when having to visit to StackExchange websites. The speed is noticeable.

If we use Pingdom Website Speed Test, we find that the load time is 571ms which is a phenomenal speed. 
[image]

I'm curious to know what are the main tricks/tactics that this site uses to be load that fast.

Comment: In one word: cache. Really. Anything that cause a load on the server is cached, giving instant access speed. This means they need LOTS of memory, but these days it's cheap enough.

Comment: Awesome! You own SE :O